# undefined method `name_cont' for Ransack::Search<class: error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I have a very simple Rails app on which I want to use Ransack search.

I get the following error though:

```
  undefined method `name_cont' for Ransack::Search<class: Post, base: Grouping     
  <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
```

I only need the basics and as per instructions in my posts controller and posts index page I put in the following code:

Posts controller:

```
def index
  @q = Post.search(params[:q])
  @posts = @q.result(:distinct => true)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @posts }
  end
end
```

Index View:

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name_cont, "Name contains" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name_cont %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Search" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue is that the method `name_cont` has not been defined in your controller. I believe whats happening here is that the search form gets an object that doesn't have `name_cont` defined which is why your getting this error. My suggestion is to define a variable name for searching the post.

Comment: It is not a case of simply defining a method called name_cont. Ransack by convention requires you to create fields such as `<attr>_cont`. Please see [the railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack).
The _Post_ model must contain an attribute called `name`.

Comment: I am also having a similar issue, getting undefined method error for 'title_cont'. pls help me to solve this ?

Comment: Is it defined in the 'ransackable_scope' in your model?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create the form with the Ransask's helper method, `form_for` is now `search_form_for`.

If you still get the same error check if your Post model has the attribute `name` [according to the documentation here](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack).